# My character pops up instead of jumping correctly

Tags: unity, character-controller

Currently my character moves around like expected except the jump. Right now it jumps but it pops up instead of a proper jump, it jolts up, teleports up. the jump works, it just pops up.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class ThirdPersonController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float walkSpeed = 6.0f;
    public float runSpeed = 11.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public float speed = 6f;
    public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
    float turnSmoothVelocity;
    float targetAngle;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;
    private CharacterController controller;
    private bool isGrounded = false;
    public Transform cam;

    private void Start()
    {
        controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 forward = cam.forward;
        forward.y = 0f;
        forward = forward.normalized;

        Vector3 right = cam.right;
        right.y = 0f;
        right = right.normalized;

        moveDirection = (right * horizontal) + (forward * vertical);

        if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero)
        {
            targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(moveDirection.x, moveDirection.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Lerp(transform.rotation, Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f), Time.deltaTime * turnSmoothTime);
        }

        if (controller.isGrounded)
        {

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                speed = runSpeed;
            }
            else
            {
                speed = walkSpeed;
            }

            if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }
        }

        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(moveDirection * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

please some enlightenment thank you.

Comment: Did you mean to keep your vertical speed persistent between frames, instead of instantly forgetting any upward velocity at the end of the frame?

Comment: @DMGregory
I thought the jumpSpeed was the velocity. Am I supposed to update every frame with a new velocity? I would think my Y movements would be just as smooth since the x and z are smooth.

Comment: `jumpSpeed` sets the vertical velocity at the moment the jump starts. The very next frame, you set `moveDirection = (right * horizontal) + (forward * vertical)` - note that there's no `(up * anything)` component there, so `moveDirection.y == 0`.

Comment: please excuse my absolute ignorance. but there isn't a string for the y axis? if I put ```(up * nameForYAxis)``` am I supposed to make a third GetAxis?  ```float yAxis = Input.GetAxis("NameforYaxis")```  that way I could put  ```( up * yAxis)```  is this what you mean or a way to do it?

Comment: Ask yourself "where is the information about how fast the player is moving vertically supposed to come from?" `Input.GetAxis` would be right if the answer was "the player pushes on a joystick or analog trigger to jetpack up and down", but that's not what's happening here. What you want is to remember the player's vertical velocity at the end of the last frame, and update from that starting point next frame.